# Load the AdventureWorks database into Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to work through some of the examples at [SQLZOO](https://sqlzoo.net/). I would like to load the AdventureWorks example database into an Oracle database at home.  Google search has not turned up any SQL scripts that have been converted for Oracle.  Does anyone have or know where I can get such scripts?

Comment: I emailed sqlzoo.qa@gmail and he sent me an sql script to load the adventureworks schema into oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-SQL and PL/SQL have variations in syntax and the concept of a database within a database is called a schema of a database in Oracle.

Oracle does supply some sample schemas that one can use for playing around, see [Database Sample Schemas](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/scripts.htm#COMSC004)

You can load the data of AdventureWorks once you have sorted out the table and associated schema creation using `bcp out` and `bcp in` or using SSIS. See [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) in the Microsoft documentation.

Doing some more digging, Oracle has [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html) and the migration process is described in [Moving Data to Oracle with Migration Workbench](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/06/moving-data-to-oracle-with-migration-workbench/) by Jeff Smith.

Answer (score 1):

Cautionary note about the SQL Developer Migration Tool: It will create a SQL Package called `SQLSERVER_UTILITIES` (if I recall correctly), which contains a load of functions that mimic some SQL Server keyword functionality that doesn't exist with the same name in Oracle, and some of these functions are horribly inefficient.

If you use the Migration Tool then it is worth making sure that what you end up with doesn't use this package but instead uses the native PL/SQL commands. Trust me, I've been there and felt the pain!

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't try to convert the AdventureWorks data for use in Oracle.

Oracle has its own demo data, which can be loaded using the scripts in `$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema`. These are documented in [Oracle® Database
Sample Schemas 11g Release 1 (11.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28328.pdf) (pdf).

Rather than sticking to the SQLZOO examples, you'd be better off starting with an Oracle-based SQL tutorial that uses the Oracle demo schemas, such as [Oracle/SQL Tutorial](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Others/tutorial.pdf) (pdf) by Michael Gertz (assuming that your aim is to learn SQL).

Answer (score 1):

I created a data set two years ago for an article I wrote for the Oracle Technology Network on Essbase Studio.

You can find the code, DDL and DML in [Oracle Essbase Sample Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/essbase-sample-522117.html)

The download in the list you want is for *Sample application accompanying the OTN tech article, "Oracle Essbase Studio Deep-Dive"* (`Oracle_Essbase_Studio_Tutorial.zip`)

Answer (score -2):

An idea . . . . 
Use a data modeler tool !
A) Import SQL Server Physical Data Model ( PDM )
B) Reverse engineer it, to get Logical Data Model (LDM )
c) Forward engineer it to Oracle ( PDM )

There you go